# How to count lines in a file and add an arbitrary number to the result?

Tags: bash, count, lines, wc

I have a file that contains 'x' lines in it.

I need to display the number of lines in such file and add 'y'.

I know that ***wc -l*** does the trick and displays 'x' as the output, how can it be so that the output would be 'x+y'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like this,

```
$ wc -l file
13 yi
$ y=12
$ wc -l file | awk -v var=$y '{print $1+var}'
25
```

Comment: Worked great exactly what I was looking for. I am a little new to awk, but it did the trick

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change what `wc -l` gives, but you can write a function that does this example:

```
# with variables to match your x y example:
mylines()
{
   x=$(cat $1 | wc -l)  # this cat is to avoid the filename in output
   y=$2
   echo $(( $x + $y ))
}
```

Example usage: `mylines somefile 19`

will add 19 to the number of lines in myfile and display the sum

Comment: good stuff, but avoid an extra process with `x=$(wc -l < $1)`.

Comment: Actually, you can change what `wc -l` gives, by changing what it gets. `cat < <( seq $n ) $file | wc -l`, for example.